# ES6 method declaration in constructor vs body?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In ES6 (ECMAScript 2015) you can define a class method either in the constructor or the body, what's the difference?

```
class Person {
 constructor(name) {
   this.name = name;

   this.sayName = () => {
     console.log('hello i am', this.name);
   }
 }
}

class Person2 {
 constructor(name) {
   this.name = name;
 }

 sayName() {
   console.log('hello i am', this.name);
 }
}
```

My guess is, in `Person`, the method `sayName` is being recreated each time we instantiate a `Person` object, and in `Person2`, we are applying the method to the prototype? (just a guess)

Comment: Your guess is right. Always use the second option if you don't need additional information during instantiation.

Comment: @Antiga is there a good example for when you might need additional information?

Comment: I mean if you are passing something in to the constructor that would modify how or which function you are attaching as a class method. Not a very good way to build a class, so I would be hard-pressed to find an example I would be happy with. Here's a good write-up: http://thecodeship.com/web-development/methods-within-constructor-vs-prototype-in-javascript/ -- same thing applies with ES2016 class.

Comment: Classes are just syntactic sugar for constructor function + prototype. The same reasons apply.